# SQL Server: most efficient way to update multiple records depending on each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to update multiple records from table "a" depending on each other. The values of the table "a" look like:

```
+------------+---------------+-------+
| date       | transfervalue | value |
+------------+---------------+-------+
| 01.03.2018 | 0             | 10    |
| 02.03.2018 | 0             | 6     |
| 03.03.2018 | 0             | 13    |
+------------+---------------+-------+
```

After the update the values of the table "a" should look like:

```
+------------+---------------+-------+
| date       | transfervalue | value |
+------------+---------------+-------+
| 01.03.2018 | 0             | 10    |
| 02.03.2018 | 10            | 6     |
| 03.03.2018 | 16            | 13    |
+------------+---------------+-------+
```

What is the most efficient way to do this? I've tried three different solutions, but the last solution doesn't work.

- Solution 1: do a loop and iterate over each day to do the update statement
- Solution 2: do an update statement statement for each day
- Solution 3: do the update for the whole timespan in one statement

The output of solution 3 was:

```
+------------+---------------+-------+
| date       | transfervalue | value |
+------------+---------------+-------+
| 01.03.2018 | 0             | 10    |
| 02.03.2018 | 10            | 6     |
| 03.03.2018 | 6             | 13    |
+------------+---------------+-------+
```

Comment: Why do I see all this html in a question about html?

Comment: what version of sql server

Comment: sql server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a cumulative sum:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, sum(value) over (order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as running_value
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set transfervalue = coalesce(running_value, 0);
```

Comment: Your solution works, thanks a lot. But i have still 1 problem... The first value is calculated wrong, if i dont update all values of the table.

Comment: @DennisF. . . . Perhaps you should ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    select t1.*, 
       coalesce((select sum(value) from table1 t2 where t2.date < t1.date), 0) MyNewValue
    from table1 t1
```